# Run second query for data not matched in first query

Tags: sql, database-design

There are two tables that have details about Books. Lets call them `BooksData1` and `BooksData2`.

I have another table that has bookIds and languages, lets call this `BookIdsAndLang`. I need to collect book data for all the bookIds and languages in the `BookIdsAndLang` table. First check the `BooksData1` table, if bookIds and languages match is found, read from the table. For bookIds and languages that were not found in `BookData1`, read from `BooksData2`. If there are bookIds and languages that are neither in `BooksData1` or `BooksData2`, then log error messages for those.

In the current implementation, BooksData1 is already inner joined with `BookIdsAndLang` on bookIds and language. Now only for bookIds and languages in `BookIdsAndLang` that were  not found in `BooksData1`, need to be looked up in `BooksData2`.

How to determine which bookIds and languages were not matched in `BooksData1`, so that they can be inner joined with `BooksData2`. Looking for a scalable solution as there may be BooksData3 and BooksData4 in future.

Solution1: Have a temporary table say `MissingBooksData`. Insert the booksIds and languages not found in 'BooksData1' into it. Then do

`BooksData2
inner join
MissingBooksData
on Ids and languages`

We need to avoid where..in clause because it has a limitation of 65536 values and this use case will easily surpass that.

Please suggest how to better design this. Thanks

Comment: What does logging an error message look like for the case when its not in booksdata1 or booksdata2? Are we to assume that a book cannot have its data in both tables data tables at once?

Comment: You have tagged this as database design; I take it we can change how the tables and that are structured? Generally having tables labelled XX1 and XX2 etc is an indication that improvements can be made.

Comment: @LordBaconPants The log will just indicate that the bookId and language could not be found in any datasource. The book can have data in both tables. In that case, BookData1 will be preferred. Yes I am open to changing the way tables are currently structured

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OUTER JOIN` to select rows in `BookIdsAndLang` which aren't in any of `BookDataN`

```
SELECT l.bookId, l.langId
FROM BookIdsAndLang l
     LEFT OUTER JOIN BookData1 b1 
        ON b1.bookId = l.bookId AND b1.langId = l.langId
     LEFT OUTER JOIN BookData2 b2 
        ON b2.bookId = l.bookId AND b2.langId = l.langId
     ...
WHERE b1.bookId IS NULL AND
      b2.bookId IS NULL AND ...
```